# Regular expressions in textarea pattern attribute to allow alphanumeric as well as special characters in combination

Tags: javascript, html, angular

There is issue in below pattern. It throws error. There is no formControl in this component.

Text area should accept all programming language(special characters) as well as strings. But it should not allow only similar special characters/numbers in sequence. Ex- `@@@@@@/######/******/111111/55555`. So that user can answer any subjective question as well as any logical programme in any computer language.

```
<textarea 
  matInput 
  placeholder="Answer here...." 
  [value]="subValue" 
  name="subjectiveValue" 
  #subValue
  required
  ngModel 
  pattern="[a-z A-Z]+[ a-zA-Z0-9=!-@#$&()>{}\\-`.+,/\]"
></textarea>
```

Comment: what's your expected result?

Comment: Expected results should be, if a user gets a question to write any programme, user can write. In programme most of the special characters are used like {}, @, = ! and many more. Text area should accept all those in combination with characters. Ex- arr.forEach( ()=> {}); or any sentence with multiple lines. But it should not allow only similar numbers/special characters in sequence as i have mentioned.

Comment: You can't do that with regex. Build your own parser instead.

Comment: A regex will be very complex because if your expected is to write some code in that text area you can write multiple special characters in sequence, think about comments (//) or boolean operators (||, &&). So i suggest you to achive your result with a form control with a custom validator